# Rails Routing with Dynamic Segments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, custom-controls

So I just started using Dynamic segments as I need them to specify certain elements for grabbing data from AWS S3 via HTTParty.

I have this match statement in my routes.rb file:

```
  match ':installation/:venue/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
```

This works great and allows me to do exactly what I want to do, which is pull in the installation and venue and use them with HTTParty to get their corresponding information from S3.

Now I need to keep my links through out persistent like these due to the fact that my application controller reads these in. So for example when I write a link_to I have had to do the following in a view/partial:

```
<%= link_to some_name,
"#{@installation}/#{@venue}/#{controller.controller_name}/show/some_id" %>
```

If it was just this ugliness I had to deal with that wouldn't be a problem, but I don't understand how I can pass around options in regards to this.

So basically is there a way to have resourceful routes for dynamic segments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use polimorphic_url
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_url

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need, so thank you very much for pointing that out. I never came across that while googling around. But when I implement this with this link_to:                  link_to menu_item.title, polymorphic_url([@installation, @venue, PoiList, 'index']), :url_options => { :map_button => map_button }       I get the following error: undefined method `SPREE_SPREE-2012_poi_lists_url' for #<#<Class:0x8f1c0cc>:0x8f1b08c>. Which means there isnt a resourceful route, correct? So how do I create resourceful routes for a match case is my question I guess?

Comment: what is your complete routes.rb ?

Comment: I ended up figuring this out, I just set my match statement like so:
    match ':installation/:venue/:controller(/:action(/:id))', :as => :default
Which gave me the resourceful routes I wanted. Thanks again for the help though.